# C# learning resources for PHP developers

Tags: c#, php, .net

I am a PHP developer however I'm looking widen my skill set. Can anyone recommend some good resources? (Online would be awesome but not necessary :) )

What are the biggest differences?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main difference is that C# is usually compiled (in a windows platform), whereas PHP is usually interpreted. C# is closer to Java in syntax, and is much more strongly typed than PHP (which is loose, weakly typed - you don't have to declare variables, etc).

If you're looking for great tutorials on C# I would personally look for books, since fundamentally valuable beginner-to-savvy instructions are more nicely consolidated in them than online.

You can look at [this post](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=597941) on SitePoint.

Comment: Well there are lots of tutorial sites out there. For example I found http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx and it is very goof.

Answer (score 1):

After looking a little bit around. I found out that c# is not really the problem. As a developer I would say that it is harder to learn ASP.NET.

That being said it needs a little explanation; If you're learning ASP.NET from sratch it's not a problem. But with a background in PHP it takes a little getting used to ASP.NET's strange and not-so-standard ways.

Comment: Coming from PHP, you might want to go with ASP.NET MVC rather than ASP.NET web forms. Still a learning curve, but MVC is probably a lot closer to what you're used to.

Comment: i agree. .net is a bit weird in how they do things. (e.g. telerik components) Though the mvc structure seems familiar.